# Share internet between ADSL router and SHDSL (Only data) router

Tags: networking, router, internet, routing, sharing

I have 2 routers :

1. ADSL Router
2. SHDSL Router (No internet, Only data are transmitted through ISP to clients)

ADSL Router is used to connect to internet.
Main SHDSL Router is used to connect company branches together (Each branch has its SHDSL Router)

Here is the map for connection

[image: Network map picture]

Clients are able to ping each others (ADSL and SHDSL)

Now what I want to share the internet from one point to other points

How to do it?

Please have a look on the photo to understand exactly what I want

I could not describe my needs in text so I draw a picture which will help you to understand my needs.

Comment: I'm sorry is this image accurate? You have 4 routers? Why on earth would you have 1 router for each user? Is your ISP in the correct place? Shouldn't it be above the router with the 192.168.1.3 ip?

Comment: clients are not located in same place! they are all connected using SHDSL connection which is managed by the ISP

but SHDSL does not have internet connection it only service data connection (leased line) so that is in image you see four routers 

2 (ADSL and SHDSL)routers are located in one site
2 (SHDSL) routers are located in two different sites

What i want is to share internet from the site that have ADSL router to sites that only have SHDSL

Comment: How can you call it an ISP if it doesn't provide internet? ISP is an INTERNET service provider. What is the purpose of providing a "service data connection"? This also sounds illegal in nature. Does the Service provider know you're doing this? I'm assuming this is in a 3rd world country?

Comment: @sickest, leased line means "private virtual connection" most of the time. It's like a VLAN through the ISPs switched network, the devices on each end see each other as if they were connected physically. It was from a time before VPN hardware was affordable...

Comment: @sickest, you need to check Tim_stewart comment to understand what I meant, and yes in some countries the ISPs provide users with such technology and it is 100% legal! also you can understand the difference between adsl and shdsl which will help you to know why people are using "service data connection", sometimes banks use "service data connections" to connect ATMs with local bank servers

Comment: Do each of the shdsl routers have the other routers populated in each devices routing table? You can use NAT/masquerading in Linux to share the internet connection to another subnet, I don't know if this is the best way to do it. Performance will depend on what's doing the masquerading & how many client devices are connecting through it.

Answer (score 0):

Configure a static route on the branch router (`192.168.11.1`) and other branch (`192.168.12.1`) as following:

```
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.3
ip route 192.168.0.0 255.255.0.0 (isp---)
```

At HQ side (`192.168.1.1`), configure the below:

```
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.3
ip route 192.168.0.0 255.255.0.0 (isp-)
```